# Где тут можно применить итератор?

Tags: python, итераторы

Прохожу курс .Где в этом задании применять итератор. Мне не нужно решение, только подсказка. Возможно надо через итератор пропускать список, и определять какой элемент в какой функции выводить. Но я могу использовать цикл for.
https://stepik.org/lesson/24464/step/4?unit=6769

Comment: Ну это как то бесчеловечно. Добавьте в вопрос саму задачу. Ваши мысли о применении. Что уже попробовали и почем это не то. Кнопка "править"

Comment: У вас же в задании есть шаблон структуры, которую должен иметь итоговый класс. И там есть метод `__iter__`. Что именно тут может быть не понятно?